# Python error in line passing parameter to command

Tags: python, parameters, command

what does this error means?

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'set' objects.

```
def main():
    print 'ffffffffffffffffffffffffff'
    try:
        print getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'u:a:s:', ['help', 'output='])
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'u:a:s:', ['help', 'output='])
        print opts, args,'print'
    except getopt.GetoptError, err:
        print str(err)
        sys.exit(2)

baseUrl = 'http://10.176.14.26:8080/client/api'
cmd = {'command : listTemplates', 'templatefilter : executable'}
api = 'Qo9Qwfatwz9ARB328Btn9PftzL2Cf5LOWd8OFyJmiM513tpTIm-zKxJoWkWqf353Df397xcLdKXGk8_JO8nM3Q'
secret = '-kgkBuBUrGFeIC4gUvngSK_3Ypmi7fuF8XdVXIusnyyiEP2YUcG3FnPUGJGy3rp3Bw5ZNnqgS-9tIfyV1QnK1g'
```

Comment: Post the full traceback so we can see where the error comes from.

Comment: At what line. I don't see '+' used to concatenate str ans set objects. Only string objects can be concatenated.

Comment: Are you sure `cmd = {'command : listTemplates', 'templatefilter : executable'}` should not be `cmd = {'command': 'listTemplates', 'templatefilter': 'executable'}`?

Comment: As @warwaruk says, `cmd` is a set. In python, `{object1, object2, ..., objectn}` is a set. Note the similarity to `{key1: value1, key2: value2, ..., keyn: valuen}`, which is a Python dict.